# Using a macro to union together unspecified number of tables in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro, enterprise-guide

I have a macro in SAS EG that reads all the csv files from a folder into SAS EG. The number of files in this folder are always changing but the columns in each file remain the same. How do I write a macro that unions together the tables that are read in?

Comment: Can you include the code for the macro you reference?  Most likely this is relatively easy but it depends on details in that macro.

Comment: Why not just read them all into one dataset to start with?

Comment: @Tom Exactly...

Comment: Did you try to simply use a wildcard in the file name? I examing all my log of the previous day with `filename /logFolder/*&yesterdays_date*.log;` and a data step;